# How to append my list elements

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a following string list

```
          List<string> myList=new List<string>();
           myList.Add("A");
           myList.Add("B");
           myList.Add("C");
           myList.Add("D");
           myList.Add("E");
           myList.Add("F");
           myList.Add("G");
           myList.Add("H");

           string Res=""
           foreach(String str in myList)
           {
               Res+=","+str;
            }
```

Is there any better method to join my List values than this ??

Thank you All

Comment: Have you tried string join method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sample code to do this with [**String.Join()**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method

```
   string delimeter = ",";

        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        str.Add("a");
        str.Add("b");
        str.Add("c");
        str.Add("d");

        string result= String.Join(delimeter, str);
```

also you could do it with **Linq**

```
      string output= str.Aggregate((i, j) => i + delimeter + j);
```

Comment: ToArray() is not necessary. Join takes an IEnumerable as a parameter.

Comment: Only from .NET 4.0 onwards, though.

Answer (score 6):

`String.Join` is what you are looking for

Have a look here at the MSDN documentation

[String.Join Method (String, String[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
string Res = String.Join("," , myList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String.Join` if you just want to concatenate them all together, or a `StringBuilder` if you're also planning on adding other text to it.

```
String.Join(", ", myList)
```